# htaccess in domain/admin laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have a laravel project hosted in mydomain.ma/admin.  When I tried my htaccess, I always get a 404 page error.

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.ma/admin$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.ma/admin$

# Exclude directory from rewriting
RewriteRule ^ressource - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pureplantessentials\.html$
```

If someone has a solution, I will be very appreciative.

Comment: Could You add the access log and the error log?

Comment: Not clear for me. what are you asking ?

Comment: i have a laravel project in a folder in my domain, so what i want is redirect domain.ma/admin to my project

Comment: `domain.ma/admin` is not a host name.

Comment: yes just a folder into my domain

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will work for make your admin directory to your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /admin/
```

Comment: when i do that i just get the list of directories (app,public,vendor,...)

Comment: Do you have an index.php in admin folder?

Comment: it a laravel project not a simple PHP with index.php

Comment: Yeah, but do you have any controller file there?